# Issues with Python and potentially other programs after home directory change

Tags: permissions, python, python3, home-directory

### Problem

Recently I changed my user name and home directory, (from `jasper-ubuntu` to `jasper` (both))
I'm concerned this may have brought some issues with Python and potentially other programs.

Something is going on with my installed version of Python, I've been told it's not the correct one and I don't know which one (and how) I should install the good one.

I've noticed this when trying to do `umake ide idea-ultimate`, everything goes fine until the program is actually ending the installation, when that happens, I get this Python (?) error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 159, in wrapper
    function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/frameworks/baseinstaller.py", line 494, in decompress_and_install_done
    add_exec_link(self.exec_path, self.exec_link_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 362, in add_exec_link
    add_env_to_user("Ubuntu Make binary symlink", {"PATH": {"value": bin_folder}})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 457, in add_env_to_user
    remove_framework_envs_from_user(framework_tag)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 441, in remove_framework_envs_from_user
    with open(profile_filepath + ".new", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jasper/.profile.new'
```

I've managed to install the program via JetBrains toolbox thanks to [Gogowitsch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/190465/gogowitsch). But the mystery remains, do I have Python properly installed? Does this have to do with me changing the home directory name?

### Relevant information

When `python3 -V` is executed, it returns:
`Python 3.8.6`

When `python -V` is executed, it returns:
`Python 3.8.6`

The package "python2" is not present on my machine.

Executing

```py
from pathlib import Path
print(Path.home())
```

Returns `/home/jasper` which is my correct actual home directory.

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.10 non-LTS

### Troubleshooting

I know this is an important step, but I specifically didn't want to tinker with Python-related things because I had to reinstall my whole machine because of issues kind of similar to these.

Comment: Depending *how* you changed your username and home directory, you may have messed up ownership and/or permission of some files. I'd start by looking at the outputs of `id` and `namei -l /home/jasper/.profile.new`

Comment: For future visitors: I suggest you check if all files in your home directory are owned by you. Run this in your Bash terminal:  `ls -GlR ~ | grep -vE 'total |'$(whoami)'|:$|^$'`. If it outputs something, you can take back ownership with `sudo chown $(whoami) ~ -R. This might resolve the "Permission denied: '/home/jasper/.profile.new'" from your question.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn‘t be any problem with your python installation since it is located under /usr/. The error seems to be a Permission denied at the end of the call stack.
This is caused by a missing permission by the IDE process which tries to open the profile.new file.

Could be fixed by locating the file and changing permissions.

You could change them from a terminal like

```
chmod -v 770 <filename>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was kinda like what I did to fix it, I'll post the answer myself.

Comment: could u then pls leave an upvote? I am still collecting my stack overflow badges =)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to give upvotes. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

### Solved

It looks like my home directory didn't belong to me, to change this, I ran nautilus as root. `sudo nautilus`, then, graphically changed the ownership of the folder and all of the subfolders to me.

This can be done via terminal as well but I haven't looked for the commands and I don't want anybody reading this to mess up, so I won't try to guess.

Thanks again to [Gogowitsch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/190465/gogowitsch) for pointing it out.